# (Oracle) Setting composite primary keys as foreign in 1 statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

lets say my table contains a set of numerous composite primary keys without an actual primary key. How can I set all those composite primary keys as foreign keys and link them to their parent tables respectively?

These 3 need to be set as foreign keys and be linked to a primary key `AgencyID` in another table.

```
AgencyID                 
PickUpAgencyID           
DropOffAgencyID
```

This one as well to another table.

```
DriverLicenseNumber
```

Is this possible to do in one go?

---

```
Create table RENTAL (

RentalAgreementNumber    Number(6)    NOT NULL,   
DriverLicenseNumber      Number(9)    NOT NULL,  
VinNumber                Number(9)    NOT NULL,
AgencyID                 Number(6)    NOT NULL,
PickUpAgencyID           Number(6)    NOT NULL,
DropOffAgencyID          Number(6)    NOT NULL,
PickUpDate               DATE         NOT NULL,
PickUpTime               TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
DropOffDate              DATE         NOT NULL,
DropOffTime              TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
PickUpOdometer           Number(6)    NOT NULL,
DropOffOdometer          Number(6)    NOT NULL,
RentalCost               Dec(8,2)     NOT NULL,
FuelOptionID             Number(2)    NOT NULL,
FuelOptionDesc           Varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
InsuranceCost            Dec(8,2)     NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: If all three of these keys are pointing to the same other table, then I'd say your database isn't normalized.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mmwfu6O.png

Comment: Why do you want it to be done in "1 statement"? why not separate statements?  Also, the design looks awful.

Comment: The syntax for several foreign keys is the same as it is for one foreign key.  You just do it more often, separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using only one [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB) command. 
Assumming that the another table names are `A` and `B`

```
alter table RENTAL
add constraint rental_a_fk foreign key (AgencyID, PickUpAgencyID, DropOffAgencyID)
    references a(AgencyID, PickUpAgencyID, DropOffAgencyID)
add constraint rental_b_fk foreign key (DriverLicenseNumber)
    references b( DriverLicenseNumber )
;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee1c26